TestDisk - None partition table type has been detected
TestDisk 7.2 is not able to detect partition table type on my external drive:
TestDisk 7.2, Data Recovery Utility, February 2024
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
https://www.cgsecurity.org


Disk /dev/sda - 2000 GB / 1862 GiB - My Passport 0748

Please select the partition table type, press Enter when done.
 [Intel  ] Intel/PC partition
 [EFI GPT] EFI GPT partition map (Mac i386, some x86_64...)
 [Humax  ] Humax partition table
 [Mac    ] Apple partition map (legacy)
>[None   ] Non partitioned media
 [Sun    ] Sun Solaris partition
 [XBox   ] XBox partition
 [Return ] Return to disk selection


Hint: None partition table type has been detected.

Can I manually pick  [Intel  ] Intel/PC partition?
Or, what can I do about this to recover the partition I deleted accidentally. I have important data in it and want to keep them. They are about 800+ GB.
I believe that my external hard drive is an NTFS file system.

This question is similar to: Recover /dev/sda to /dev/sda1? which you asked a few days ago. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@graham this one is more specific using TestDisk

Typically better to use Windows tools for Windows & Linux tools for Linux. Sometime Linux tools can do limited repairs on Windows but not vice-versa. You may do better on a Windows site. Another alternative is Photorec, but again Windows tools may be better for NTFS. https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step  I have used photorec before better backups. On smaller drive took overnight & you need another drive to copy recovered data into. Only recovers by type/extension, not full file name. Took me weeks to rename files.

@oldfred I found a better tool to recover my data on Linux - https://dmde.com/ you don't need to rename the files. You can select what data you want to recover. way better than Photorec
